# How do i launch my jenkins-cli through docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, scripting, jenkins-cli

i have created the docker image that installs java,jenkins,jenkins-cli. now i need to pass some argument through jenkins-cli, so i need to launch jenkins-cli. How do i do it? i have no idea how it launches.

Here is my script

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt update; \
  apt upgrade -y; \
  apt install -y default-jdk curl wget git maven nano unzip; \
  apt-get clean
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get autoclean $$ apt-get clear cache
RUN apt-get -yqq update 
RUN apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip
RUN apt-get update

# copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir /jenkins/
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion

#jenkin-cli installation
RUN cd /tmp && curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar 
ADD /tmp/jenkins-cli.jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins-cli.jar
WORKDIR /opt/jenkins
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "jenkins-cli.jar", "-noCertificateCheck", "-noKeyAuth"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

this is error:

```
Step 19/24 : RUN cd /tmp && curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9a6210009f84
Step 20/24 : ADD jenkins-cli.jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar
ADD failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder945232568/jenkins-cli.jar: no such file or directory[1]
```

This error is causing me for  may other build too,if i can find best solution i can solve my all other problems.
2nd question is, is my scripting for my current problem is right? How can i modify?

Can anyone help me with this..?
thank u in advance

Comment: Update: i changed the WORKDIR to /tmp
Now the build is success but im unable to run. does my updation is wrong, or there any other way to Run it???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create the `/opt/jenkins` folder

Change

```
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
```

to

```
RUN mkdir /opt/jenkins
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

Comment: can u link me to any of related video or how to run, coz im unable to download jenkins-cli now after implementing ur suggetion

Comment: how can i run that image?
docker run -it <imageid> ?  or is there diffrent way?

Answer (score 1):

Given your cli tool is available from within your container with a simple command such as `cli-tool_command`  this should work:

```
docker run --rm -it {container_image_name} {cli_tool_command} {cli_tool_args}
```

Comment: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.